# Is it possible to prove $ac+bd\geq \frac{1}{2}$ if $(a+c)(b+d)=1$?

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If I prove $ac+bd\geq \frac{1}{2},$ then I solve another inequality that I have been trying to solve. This one seems simple enough, but I have already spent 30 min on it. I was wondering if it is even possible to prove this using the condition given or should I just give up on this approach? If it is possible, I was wondering if I could get a hint.

Edit:
$a,b,c,d$ are positive reals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counter example: $a = b = 1$ and $c = d = 0$

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I forgot to mention that $a,b,c,d$ have to be positive reals. I'll go add it right now.

Comment: @BananaBlitzCoding Then try $\,a=b=0.9\,$ and $\,c=d=0.1\,$. Or, in fact, any $\,a,b\in (0,1) \setminus \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $\,c=1-a, \,d=1-b\,$.

Answer (score 2):

If you exclude the counterexample in the accepted answer and restrict a, b, c, d > 0, I think you get the inequality holding if $(a^2 + b^2) < (a^2 - b + c) \epsilon$, for some small $\epsilon$.

I got there by letting $(a + c) = 1 + \epsilon$, so $1 = (b + d) + \frac{\epsilon}{a + c}$, wlog assume $a \geq 1/2$, $b \leq 1/2$, then use the above equations to get $ac = a(1 + \epsilon -a)$, $bd = b(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{a + c} - b)$

Multiplying these expressions through for ac and bd and adding them and rearranging gives $-a^2 -b^2 + a \epsilon - \frac{b \epsilon}{a + c} + b < a - 1/2$.

Since $b > 0$ a little rearrangement gives the expression I came up with.

I feel like there is a cleaner solution but I think the inequality is generally true if the counterexample is excluded.

Comment: There are lots of counter examples with positive a,b,c,d as dxiv mentions. You can’t say that an inequality is true if only you ignore all the places it is false...

Comment: Probably true ... oh well, senility sets in, it's a beautiful thing. Just wait for it!